# Cannot find name although it's not referenced typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to access a value inside of an if statement looking like this :

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const token = getFromStorage("token");

  

  if (token) {
    const { data, error } = useQuery(
      ["username", token],
      () => getCurrentUser(token),
      { enabled: token.length > 0 }
    );
  }


  return (
    <div className="flex items-center w-full custom-container  self-center py-3 px-4 ">
  <Link href="/">
    <a className="text-2xl text-pgreen font-bold"> conduit</a>
  </Link>

  <div className="flex ml-auto ">
    <ul className="">
      <Link href="" className=" ">
        <a className="text-gray-400 text-base hover:text-gray-600   w-fit h-fit pr-3 ">
          Home
        </a>
      </Link>

      
      {token && data ? (
        <Link href="" className="">
          <a className="text-gray-400 text-base hover:text-gray-600  w-fit h-fit pr-3">
            {data?.user?.username}
          </a>
        </Link>
      ) : null}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  );
};
```

I'm trying to use the data i'm getting from the useQuery hook from react query , but data is not being read at the bottom within my jsx and i get the cannot find name error

Comment: While `useQuery` seems very similar to `react-query` it's good to document that in the question

Comment: How are those random code blocks linked to each other? What is their order of execution? Can you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: @niceman I've edited the post and i hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

`const` and `let` are block scope variable definition statements, so with this code:

```
if(somecondition){ // the if starts a block scope here
    const b = 2;
    console.log(b); // won't throw
} // and ends its block scope here
console.log(b); // will throw, b is outside the scope
```

And that's what's happening in your example.

The obvious solution is to define `data` and `error` like this:

```
let data, error;

if (token) {
  const query = useQuery(["username", token], () => getCurrentUser(token), {
      enabled: token.length > 0,
  });
  data = query.data;
  error = query.error;
}
```

But I'll give myself the freedom to tell you some problems with your code.

According to Rules of hooks, hooks even custom ones should always be used top level, so the following code violates this rule:

```
if(somecondition){
  useSomeHook() // be it built-in hook like useState or custom hook
}
```

the rule is explained in React's docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). quoting:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

Refactoring your code for the best-practice we have this instead:

```
const token = getFromStorage("token");
const { data, error } = useQuery(
  ["username", token],
  () => getCurrentUser(token),
  {
    enabled: token && token.length > 0, // this way if token doesn't exists enabled will be false and query won't execute
  }
);
```

Applying this rule may not have any effect in your example but React docs explain the reason behind that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), quoting:

> As we learned earlier, we can use multiple State or Effect Hooks in a single component:

```
function Form() {
  // 1. Use the name state variable
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');

  // 2. Use an effect for persisting the form
  useEffect(function persistForm() {
    localStorage.setItem('formData', name);
  });

  // 3. Use the surname state variable
  const [surname, setSurname] = useState('Poppins');

  // 4. Use an effect for updating the title
  useEffect(function updateTitle() {
    document.title = name + ' ' + surname;
  });

  // ...
}
```

> So how does React know which state corresponds to which
> useState call? The answer is that React relies on the order in which
> Hooks are called. Our example works because the order of the Hook
> calls is the same on every render:

```
// ------------
// First render
// ------------
useState('Mary')           // 1. Initialize the name state variable with 'Mary'
useEffect(persistForm)     // 2. Add an effect for persisting the form
useState('Poppins')        // 3. Initialize the surname state variable with 'Poppins'
useEffect(updateTitle)     // 4. Add an effect for updating the title

// -------------
// Second render
// -------------
useState('Mary')           // 1. Read the name state variable (argument is ignored)
useEffect(persistForm)     // 2. Replace the effect for persisting the form
useState('Poppins')        // 3. Read the surname state variable (argument is ignored)
useEffect(updateTitle)     // 4. Replace the effect for updating the title

// ...
```

> As long as the order of the Hook calls is the same between
> renders, React can associate some local state with each of them. But
> what happens if we put a Hook call (for example, the persistForm
> effect) inside a condition?

```
//  We're breaking the first rule by using a Hook in a condition
if (name !== '') {
  useEffect(function persistForm() {
    localStorage.setItem('formData', name);
  });
}
```

> The name !== '' condition is true on the first render, so we run this Hook. However, on the next render the user might clear the
> form, making the condition false. Now that we skip this Hook during
> rendering, the order of the Hook calls becomes different:

```
useState('Mary')           // 1. Read the name state variable (argument is ignored)
// useEffect(persistForm)  //  This Hook was skipped!
useState('Poppins')        //  2 (but was 3). Fail to read the surname state variable
useEffect(updateTitle)     //  3 (but was 4). Fail to replace the effect
```

> React wouldn’t know what to return for
> the second useState Hook call. React expected that the second Hook
> call in this component corresponds to the persistForm effect, just
> like during the previous render, but it doesn’t anymore. From that
> point, every next Hook call after the one we skipped would also shift
> by one, leading to bugs.
>
> This is why Hooks must be called on the top level of our components.
> If we want to run an effect conditionally, we can put that condition
> inside our Hook: